# Why there is no power operator in Java / C++?

Tags: java, c++, python

While there is such operator - `**` in Python, I was wondering why Java and C++ don't have one too.

It is easy to make one for classes you define in C++ with operator overloading (and I believe such thing is possible also in Java), but when talking about primitive types such as int, double and so on, you'll have to use library function like `Math.power` (and usually have to cast both to double).

So - why not define such an operator for primitive types?

Comment: In C++, we cannot create our own operators. You can only overload the existing operators.

Comment: @Mahesh , so i can create my own Number class and overload ^ operator to be a power. That realy doesnt mather.

Comment: @RanZilber: It does matter because the precedence of the `^` operator do not match the precedence of exponentiation. Consider the expression `a + b ^ c`. In mathematics, the exponentiation is performed first (`b ^ c`), then the resulting power is added to `a`. In C++, the addition is performed first (`a + b`) then the `^` operator is performed with `c`. So even if you did implement the `^` operator to mean exponentiation, the precedence will surprise everyone.

Comment: *It is easy to make one for classes you define in C++ with operator overloading ( and i believe such thing is possible also in java)* you can't overload operators in Java. Also pow makes sense for floating point numbers only, so it's a bit weird. Plus, it's just too rare to need it.

Comment: @in silico - Ok then , so why not using one of operator in second line of http://www.difranco.net/cop2220/op-prec.htm ? Right to left assositive , and high enough precedence.

Comment: @RamZilber - `^` is an XOR in C++. It is advised that overloaded operator should do no different what a primitive data type does using it.

Comment: @RanZilber: Because it's not at all intuitive to use any of those operators you mention to mean exponentiation. I would seriously question the competence of any C++ programmer that overloads the `++` operator or the `!` operator et. al. to mean exponentation. But you can't anyway, because the operators you talk about accept only one argument; exponentiation requires two arguments.

Comment: Looking at that table the only binary operator with high enough precedence in C++ is `->`. And it has left associativity which doesn't fit. And that doesn't even touch on the issue that `->` has a completely different meaning from exponentiation. SO I'd question the sanity of anyone overloading it for such a purpose.

Comment: Also, is it so much work to use the Math.pow method? http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: @CodesInChaos `->` is not a binary operator for the purpose of overloading.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Generally speaking, the primitive operators in C (and by extension C++) are designed to be implementable by simple hardware in roughly a single instruction. Something like exponentiation often requires software support; so it's not there by default.

Also, it's provided by the standard library of the language in the form of `std::pow`.

Finally, doing this for integer datatypes wouldn't make much sense, because most even small values for exponentiation blow out the range required for int, that is up to 65,535. Sure, you could do this for doubles and floats but not ints, but why make the language inconsistent for a rarely used feature?

Comment: While I agree with most of this, the fact that the modulus operator can not be used on floating point types is inconsistent for primitive data types, but that too probably would not be a single instruction on any hardware I imagine is any way prevalent now.

Comment: @Sion: At least on x86, modulus is a single instruction. (`DIV` does both division and modulus) You've got me on the consistency point though.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Floating point modulus in a single instruction? I haven't mucked around in assembly as of late to know for my self. If that's the case, then the modulus operator should be made applicable to floating point types.

Comment: @Sion: No, not floating point modulus. Integer modulus. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Arithmetic (Specifically DIV -> "Remainder Stored In")

Comment: Right, I'm saying that it's inconsistent because floating point doesn't have modulus, but integers do, and that makes sense because floating point modulus isn't usually a single instruction.

Comment: @sbi: Thanks for cleaning that up -- I shouldn't try to answer a SO question at 4AM lol.

Comment: @Billy: I was startled by the first one, the others were found by FF's spillchucker. `:)`

Comment: Languages that do have built-in exponentiation also tend to have built-in bignum support. (Yes, this takes a _lot_ of library code.)

Comment: @DonalFellows: FORTRAN had the exponentiation operator long before it had anything resembling bignum support.

Comment: @supercat And it makes sense for floating point numbers (whereas C uses `pow()`). It's just not very useful for integers without bignums. My favorite language has both bignums and an exponentiation operator (with syntax shamelessly stolen from Fortran, of course).

Comment: @DonalFellows: A power operator isn't as useful with integers as with floats, but for small powers (especially squaring) it could definitely have its uses.  Personally I like the approach of making operators out of letters (as Pascal does with `div` or FORTRAN with `.EQ.`); depending upon the language whitespace rules, it may be possible to have arbitrary number of operators without requiring that they be reserved words.

Comment: @supercat That (arbitrary operators) depends largely on how much magic you put in the lexer/parser. Some languages manage it; others don't bother with that sort of fanciness. (All letter tokens for operators aren't a problem _per se_ of course.)

Comment: @DonalFellows: It also depends upon whitespace rules.  If one were to require "letter operators" be surrounded by periods and whitespace, [e.g. `i1 .div. i2`] and forbid whitepsace after periods used for member access, then lexing would be easy.

Comment: @supercat Consider Perl's `eq` operator (string equality). There, you just put a space in if you need it…

Comment: @DonalFellows: Is `eq` a reserved word?  Having in-line operators be reserved words is easy for parsing, but loses one of the big advantages of "letter operators"--the ability to define more should there be a need for them.  Period-delineated operators may seem antiquated, but to my eye the periods add a good amount of visual distinctiveness.

Comment: @supercat Reserved words are just letter-based tokens with their own class in the lexer output. (I don't know if it is a reserved word or something more horrific; it's ___Perl___ after all!)

Comment: @DonalFellows: Some languages may be parsed completely without having to use a symbol table, and there's no way that symbol definitions can affect the way things are parsed [personally, I favor such designs].  If different non-reserved-word letter-token operators have different precedence and associativity, there will be a limit as to how well things can be parsed without having to consult the symbol table, though it might be practical to say that an expression without parentheses will simply parse as a list of operands and operators, which will be grouped into sub-expressions during...

Comment: ...semantic analysis--at least if whitespace is required between an alphanumeric operator and a succeeding open parenthesis, and whitespace is forbidden between a function call and its arguments [IMHO not unreasonable restrictions, though I don't know what languages if any parse things that way].

Answer (score 45):

This question is answerable for C++:  Stroustrup, "Design and Evolution of C++" discusses this in section 11.6.1, pp. 247-250.

There were general objections to adding a new operator.  It would add to the already overcomplicated precedence table.  The members of the working group thought it would give only minor convenience over having a function, and they wanted to be able to substitute their own functions sometimes.

There was no good candidate for an operator.  `^` is exclusive-or, and `^^` invited confusion because of the relationship between `&` and `|` and `&&` and `||`.  `!` was unsuitable since there would be the natural tendency to write `!=` for exponentiation of an existing value, and that was already taken.  The best available may have been `*^`, which apparently nobody really liked.

Stroustrup considered `**` again, but it already has a meaning in C:  `a**p` is `a` times whatever `p` points to, and `char ** c;` declares `c` as a pointer to pointer to `char`.  Introducing `**` as a token meaning "declaration of a pointer to pointer to", "times what the next thing points to" (if it's a pointer) or "exponentiation" (if followed by a number) caused precedence problems.  `a/b**p` would have to parse as `a/(b**p)` if p were a number, but `(a/b) * *p` if p were a pointer, so this would have to be resolved in the parser.

In other words, it would have been possible, but it would have complicated the precedence table and the parser, and both are already too complicated.

I don't know the story about Java; all I could do would be speculate.  As for C, where it started, all C operators are easily translated into assembly code, partly to simplify the compiler and partly to avoid hiding time-consuming functionality in simple operators (the fact that `operator+()` and others could hide great complexity and performance hits was one of the early complaints about C++).

Comment: Nice answer. I guess Java tried to be simplified C in this respect, so nobody wanted to add a new operator. That's a pity that nobody asked me, I surely would have liked `*^`. :D

Comment: C was built to do text formatting. Fortran was built to do maths and had complex, power and matrix maths 20 years earlier.

Comment: @Martin Beckett:  Can you find evidence that C was built for text formatting?  It seems to me a very clumsy language for that, and what I've read about the origin of C says it was designed for system programming for Unix primarily.

Comment: @DavidThornley - It was designed to write Unix in, but all the early Unix uses seem to have been text formatting, and for it's time it has an extensive string and i/o library.

Comment: +1: The existing meaning for `a**p` is the killer. (The hacks to work around that problem… Brr!)

Comment: @DavidThornley, The "there was no good candidate for an operator" seems like an excuse. It's totally fine to use something like `pow` or `power` or `$pow` or `\pow` which is clear and straightforward. What's with the fetish for pure non-letter symbols?

Answer (score 14):

I *suspect* it's because every operator you introduce increases the complexity of the language. The barrier for entry is therefore very high. I find myself using exponentiation very, very rarely - and I'm more than happy to use a method call to do so.

Comment: [Every feature starts out with -100 points.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx)

Comment: I'd use `x**2` and `x**3` not that rarely. And a magic pow implementation that the compiler knows about and optimizes for the simple cases would be nice.

Comment: @CodeInChaos:  However `x * x` and `x * x * x` aren't bad substitutes for the square and cube.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - c++ does, the pow function is overloaded for float and int exponents

Comment: @David you can't simply write `x*x` if x is an expression. In the best case the code becomes unwieldy, and in the worst slower or even wrong. So you'd need to define your own Square and Cube functions. And even then the code would be uglier than using ** as power operator.

Comment: @CodeInChaos:  You couldn't simply write `x**2` if `x` were an expression; you'd have to parenthesize it in the same way.  Assuming your compiler has common subexpression elimination, the compiled code won't be bigger or slower.

Comment: @David I need to put parentheses yes, but don't need to repeat the expression several times and bloats the source-code. Which reduces readability a lot. And common subexpression elimination is only possible if the compiler can guarantee the expression being free of side effects. And at least .net jitter isn't too smart in that regard.

Comment: In Ada, using BASE**SOME_EXPONENT is used very often. It's part of the language. But it does not have pointer syntax, though you can do pointers.

Answer (score 11):

The Java language and core library designers decided to relegate most math operations to the [Math](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class. See [Math.pow()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29).

Why? Flexibility to prioritize performance over bit-for-bit precision. It would go against the rest of the language spec to say that the behavior of built-in math operators could vary from platform to platform, whereas the Math class specifically states that the behavior potentially sacrifices precision for performance, so buyer beware:

> Unlike some of the numeric methods of
>   class [StrictMath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html), all implementations
>   of the equivalent functions of class
>   Math are not defined to return the
>   bit-for-bit same results. This
>   relaxation permits better-performing
>   implementations where strict
>   reproducibility is not required.

Answer (score 6):

Exponentiation was part of Fortran from the beginning because it was aimed squarely at scientific programming.    Engineers and physicists use it often in simulations, because power law relationships are common in physics.

Python has a strong presence in scientific computing, too (e.g. NumPy and SciPy).  That, along with its exponentiation operator, suggest that it was aimed at scientific programming, too.

C, Java, and C# have roots in system programming.  Perhaps that's an influence that kept exponentiation out of the group of supported operators.

Just a theory.

Answer (score 4):

C defined operators only for common arithmetic operations accessible with the ALU. Its main aim was creating a human-readable interface to Assembly code.

C++ did not change any operator behaviour because it wanted all the code base written in C to be compliant.

Java did the same because it didn't want to intimidate existing C++ programmers.

Comment: When C was created, multiplication and division were not infrequently lacking in hardware and had to be implemented in software.  Yet C has multiplication and division operators.

Comment: @siride: To my knowledge, the PDP-7 the first computer to run Unix, had hardware multiplication and division through its EAE. Please see: http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp7/F-75_PDP-7userHbk_Jun65.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Well because every operator that would make sense for a power is already in use. ^ is XOR and ** defines a pointer to a pointer. So instead they just have a function that does the same thing. (like pow())

Comment: @RTS - Does a langauge developer is realy looking for sense more than efficieny ?

Comment: A good developer of a programming language looks at both. I can't say anything about java. But in c++ the pow() function is computed at compile time. And is just as efficient as the regular operators.

Comment: @RTS: The `pow()` function performs its computation at runtime, unless you got a compiler that can do constant folding for `pow()`, which I highly doubt. (Some compilers give you the option of using processor intrinsics to perform the calculation, however.)

Comment: @In silico I didn't mean that it computes the final value, I meant that the compilers will optimize away the function call, so you just have the raw equation.

Comment: The pointer to a pointer is not a good reason,  simple pointers already use the same symbol as multiplication.

Comment: @josefx:  Sure it's a good reason.  A single `*` is a lexical token, whether it's used for indirection or multiplication.  A `**` meaning exponentiation would be either one or two lexical tokens, and you really don't want your lexer to have to hit the symbol table to tokenize.

Answer (score 0):

Fact is, arithmetic operators are only shortcuts of functions. (Nearly) Everything you do with them can be done with a function. Example:

```
c = a + b;
// equals
c.set(a.add(b));
// or as free functions
set(c, add(a,b));
```

It's just more verbose, so I see nothing wrong with using functions to perform 'power of'.

Answer (score -1):

Addition/subtraction/negation and multiplication/division are basic mathematical operators. If you were to make power an operator, where would you stop? Square root operator? N-root operator? Logarithm operator?

I can't speak for their creators, but I can say that I think it'd become unwieldy and not orthogonal to have such operators in the language. The number of non alpha-numeric/white-space characters remaining on the keyboard are rather limited. As it is, it's strange that there's a modulus operator in C++.

Comment: +1 - I don't see why having `mod` as an operator is strange. It's usually a single instruction. It's a primative operation on integers. It's used most everywhere in computer science. (Implementing things like bounded buffers without `mod` would stink)

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Strange because of the inconsistency between being able to use with integer types and floating point types. Absolutely useful though and I wouldn't dream of removing it. Just quirky is all.